# Program is OK. But no output is coming

Tags: python-3.x

The code has no error when I run for `repeat = 2` or `3`. It works at that time. But when I give `repeat = 5` or more the program just freezes! Can any one give me a faster solution of this program so that it works for any integer as a value of repeat in my program.

```
#here the text file is empty
import itertools
s=open("pp.txt","w")

def main(i):
    result = ''.join(tuple(map(str,i)))
    s.write("%s," % result)

u=list(map(chr,range(32,127)))
c=list(itertools.product(u,repeat=5))
r=map(main,c)

print(list(r))
s.close()
```

Comment: You are attempting to create a list `c` with a length of like 8 billion string values. What exactly are you tasked with doing?

Comment: With a repeat of 5, your current solution looks like it would require about 550 gig of memory.